# How can I set "password123" as my password in HTML login page

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to set "password123" as my password in my HTML login page.I need help from you to set the particular password in the below given source code.Please help me to validate my password

login.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function validation()
      {
        var a = document.form.pass.value;
        if(a=="")
        {
          alert("Please Enter Your Password");
          document.form.pass.focus();
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()" action="class_info.html">
      <tr>
        <td> password:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pass"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check if the typed password is equal to `password123`, right?

If so,

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function validation()
      {
        var a = document.form.pass.value;
        var valid = true;       
        if(a=="")
        {
          valid = false;
          alert("Please Enter Your Password");
        }
        else if (a != 'password123') {
          valid = false;
          alert("Your Password is wrong");
        }

        if (valid) {
          alert('form submitted'); 
        }
        else {
          document.form.pass.focus();
          return false; 
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()" action="class_info.html">
      <tr>
        <td> password:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pass"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second Comparison to your code:

```
if(a==="password123") {
    alert("correct Password");
    return true;
}
```

login.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function validation() {
        var a = document.form.pass.value;
        if(a=="") {
          alert("Please Enter Your Password");
          document.form.pass.focus();
          return false;
        } else if(a==="password123") {
            alert("correct Password");
            return true;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()" action="class_info.html">
      <tr>
        <td> password:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pass"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```